# Node Express Installation Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Hi I am trying to install Node Express Framwork . But its Throwing following error**

```
rajdeep@rajdeep-Lenovo-G50-80:/var/www/mynode$ npm install -g express-generator
npm WARN locking Error: EACCES, open '/home/rajdeep/.npm/_locks/express-generator-981ece2c3651799f.lock'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
npm WARN locking  /home/rajdeep/.npm/_locks/express-generator-981ece2c3651799f.lock failed { [Error: EACCES, open '/home/rajdeep/.npm/_locks/express-generator-981ece2c3651799f.lock']
npm WARN locking   errno: -13,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES',
npm WARN locking   path: '/home/rajdeep/.npm/_locks/express-generator-981ece2c3651799f.lock' }
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-30-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "express-generator"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! Attempt to unlock /usr/lib/node_modules/express-generator, which hasn't been locked
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/mynode/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

When installing global modules, you (depends on how you installed node/npm) need to execute the install command as root, so:

```
sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

Comment: but by using root i am not able to edit file inside the folder

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz6Q6.png  Can you See My app Is locked  ..  If i change the mode or take the ownership . the other folder like view , public route become locked

Comment: Install `express-generator` with `sudo`, but don't *use* it with `sudo`, run it normally.

Comment: not able to create and delete file inside the View folder after using `Sudo`

Answer (score 0):

You can install with super user previlages, as mentioned above. But you won't be able to edit files in that.

```
             sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

After installation just go to the directory where you want to create your application and type

```
            express test
```

Then

```
            cd test
            npm install
```

After all this is done just change the permissions of your working directory i.e test. Now edit the files using your editor and run as you do, thank you.

Comment: i am fighting with permission

Comment: i.stack.imgur.com/Fz6Q6.png Can you See My app Is locked .. If i change the mode or take the ownership . the other folder like view , public route become locked

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the screenshots, you are trying to install/create files in `/var/www` which is surely not owned by your user. In linux you should use your **home** folder to do stuff, SO I would suggest you to create a **Projects** folder ( `~/Projects`) inside your home and try to run the express command from there.

Or if you really want to use `/var/www` you should give permissions to your user to write/read in that folder and then you can execute your command from there (without sudo).